# Is it a good practise to timestamp all filenames in a multiuser website?

Tags: javascript, php, file, timestamp

My pseudo code is  basically,

The JavaScript code reads the uploaded files and time stamps the different files with jquery.now() in a loop then uploads the file with the corresponding file objects and timestamped filename and inserts it into a MySQL database.

My question is, if many users decide to upload items is there a chance that the time stamps would be same if they click the submit button at the same time ?

Comment: Probably. You could always have a timestamp + random 5 characters of the MD5 of the file, that will probably resolve your issue

Comment: If the timestamp is made in the exact same time then yes they can be identical. But since you store them in a database you can use an auto increment id to differentiate them. So I don't think you really need a timestamp. Or are you only storing the file location in the database and not the file itself?

Comment: You should also get the current time in PHP, because on the client side the user could manipulate the .now() method or send garbage like '-3433432' for the current time.

Comment: @MarkBaijens yes i'm just storing the filenames in the database. The files are uploaded to a folder on the server. The db structure where the filenames are stored has three fields, id(unique), cid( id to retrieve relevant files from another db id), filename.

Comment: If a user has a unique username or id you can use that to create a submap for each user. And @AndreasWeswaldi suggestion is good. Add your timestamp in PHP. Client side inputs can always be manipulated.

Comment: No that will not be possible as the timestamp is determined before the items are uploaded and the user may not be registered too.  However as you have said if it's a millisecond same then it may affect it so i'll try to explore some other options probably having a different timestamp while there are other connections or something .

Comment: You could keep track of the amount of files saved and add an iteration number to the filename. Important is that you make sure 2 treads can't be saving a file at the same time.

Comment: Would it be ok if i inserted the post details, got the last insert id,  and then uploaded the files with their timestamps ?